# GFCI wont work correctly

Tags: electrical, gfci

i have an older, 1930ish, home with only 2 conductors on the branch circuits. im trying to install GFCI outlets in kit/baths. im running new romex to the single-pole Pushmatic (ancient, i know) breakers. There is only 1 neutral bar in the panel, w/white wire and a few bare ground wires connected. im connecting the neutral and the ground conductors to that bar. im getting 115v on the hot side, a circuit indication on my wiggy from the bneutral side, but no power through the GFC, brand new ones. Do i need a better ground for the house? Also, as i disconnect (while still hot) the black wire on the feed side, i get momentary flickers from the LEDindicator  on the GFCI. A good connection results , again, in a no power situation. It doesnt trip so cant be reset, just nothing, despite a good ac supply and good neutral. Help?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange. Is your GFCI rated for 2 wire ? I know in the past there were special models for 2 wire. The ground and neutral on the same buss in the main panel is fine and should not cause a problem. Are you sure you have the hot on the line side Brass screw and the neutral on the line side silver screw. this would be the only other thing unless it is a bad GFCI.

Comment: yeah, ive chkd connection, polarity (i worked2 yrs w/2 masters)...very strange--dyou think i could 2 3-packs of bad devices?

Comment: Some GFCIs need you to press their test button and then reset them when they are first installed to get them to work.

Comment: Upgrade that pushmatic panel before it burns your house down.

Comment: What's the make and model of the GFCIs?

Comment: You've got major problems w/ ground and neutral there.  I'd fix those before even starting to worry about GFCI.

Answer (score 2):

Do not alter wiring of energized circuits.  **ALWAYS turn off the power.**

I've never heard of any GFCI that cares about about ground. The point of a GFCI is they can provide protection even when a ground is not provided.

GFCIs have an "in" and an "out".  You must not reverse these.  The "in" is labeled LINE and the "out" is labeled LOAD.  Make sure you're wiring the power from the panel into the LINE terminals.

Comment: for many years there were specific models that were required on job sites for this reason. You must be very young and or not a profesional licensed electrian.

Comment: Hey Ed, care to be more specific? I'm having trouble understanding which parts of this answer you're disagreeing with.